# colab runtime died, automatically restarting

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, kaggle

when I am trying to do Adaboosting in Colab for a kaggle competition, the project is here https://www.kaggle.com/c/competitive-data-science-predict-future-sales, it will definitely "runtime died, automatically restarting".
Then, I googled some answers, one method is saying "you can type '`!/opt/bin/nvidia-smi`' before doing calculation. the output after doing it
 is:

```
Fri Sep 28 00:48:45 2018       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.111                Driver Version: 384.111                   |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K80           Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   36C    P8    33W / 149W |      0MiB / 11439MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found
```

Thus I make sure I have all the memory, but no matter how I run my code:

```
adb_reg = AdaBoostRegressor(base_estimator=None, n_estimators=20, learning_rate=1.0, loss='linear', random_state=None)
adb_reg.fit(df[predictors],np.ravel(df[response]), sample_weight=None)
```

I will get "runtime died...". After "enjoying" this kind of failure; can I say Colab is just a toy, and I need to find another way to do kaggle project? any suggestions?

Comment: Try sampling the data set to see if the problem is indeed crashing OOM. If so, there are many things you can try, e.g., reducing the batch size during training.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I really wish someone can have a explict and detailed answer. This issue is really pretty annoying.